# Integrating a ratio of polynomials $\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}$ on the real line?

Tags: calculus, integration, polynomials, improper-integrals

Let $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ be some polynomials. What conditions ensure that the integral
$$
I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{g(x)}{h(x)}dx
$$
is absolutely integrable? Obviously $h(x)$ has to be of higher degree than $g(x)$, but is there a more precise condition on when this expression is absolutely integrable?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it will entirely depend on whether the degree of $h(x)$ is two higher than that of $g(x)$.

Comment: Assume common factors are removed. You need $g$ to be at least two degrees smaller than $h$, and $h$ cannot vanish anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be integrable at all the singularities, namely, $\infty$ and the real poles.

At infinity you have $$\frac{g(x)}{h(x)} \sim C x^{deg(g)-deg(h)}$$
So $h$ has to be of degree higer or equal to $deg(g)+2$.

If $g$ and $h$ don't have common factors, at the real poles you get $$\frac{g(x)}{h(x)} \sim \frac{C}{(x-a)^n}$$ which is never absolutly integrable. So $h$ can't have poles.